# Dungeon Crasher vs Wall of Bones

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, class-feature, forced-movement

The life of a dungeoncrasher is hard, especially if your dm has ruled that you can't (or you see as too easy to) crash against the floor. Sometimes, you find yourself in an endless plain and need walls on demand.

One of the lowest level solid wall spells, the tiny and melee Blockade notwithstanding, is Wall of Bones,  which can be crossed with a full round action and possibly checks, but not without them.

The question is, does this make these walls solid enough for dungeoncrasher? Which is, I suppose, synonymous to, do they block forced movement?

Comment: @J.Mini Pleaes don't answer, even partially, in comments. [We try not to do that here.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533)

Comment: @NautArch That's not an answer, it's a suggestion. The question has nothing to do with what spells are good.

Comment: Dark way has a lot of issues as a wall substitute. Put simply, it relies on DM approval and, if it recieves it, gives everything needed to make them regret it.

Comment: Oh, I removed the wall of chains from the body because, dumb me, it has no such clause and is actually impassable. I mixed it up with some other spell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description of the 4th-level wu jen spell ***wall of bones*** [conj] (*Complete Arcane* 128–9), in part, says, "Though solid, the wall has many small openings and gaps and creatures on either side have cover and concealment against attacks from, the opposite side." So, although it can be bypassed with effort ("Small creatures can slip and wiggle through the wall at will, but a Medium creature" must succeed on an Escape Artist skill check or else be dealt damage by and stuck in the *wall of bones* effect), the game says the *wall of bones* effect is, in fact, solid.

The description of the fighter alternative class feature **dungeon crasher**, in part, says that the creature gains "a special benefit when making a bull rush. If you [i.e. the creature] force an opponent to move into a wall or other solid object, he stops as normal" (*Dungeonscape* 10).

Because it's described both as solid *and* as a wall, this DM would have no issue with ruling that a dungeon crasher fighter could, with a successful enough bull rush attempt, dash a foe against a *wall of bones* effect. Verisimilitude may be strained when the fighter crushes a cat, songbird, or squirrel against the *wall of bones* effect, but, then again, knocking enemies into walls is this fantasy warrior's jam—being talented enough at bull rushing so as to aim a little foe at the *wall of bones* effect's more solid parts should come with the territory.